# Have dynamic size using window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must use the window.open to open a url. But I want it to be dynamic(the width) according to the content on the loaded url How can I achive this?

Comment: it is depend on browser to browser

Comment: Ok can I do It with jQuery? If not give me an example of a browser and I can search for solutions to the others

Comment: you can use `https://api.jquery.com/resize/` to achieve this

Comment: Thanks but thats an event listener for when a window is resized. I dont think it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. You can set a start up width though, which you yourself can calculate:

```
window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
```

UPDATED

After some thinking there might be a way to "calculate" the content width.

If you load your url in a not visible iframe, you could actually get a value from the iframe content by querying its width.

And if you use ASP/PHP, you could do this server side too, which would save you issues with the iframe.

ASP has the webclient which can be used, PHP I don't know but for sure has something else.

Comment: I dont know the size before its loaded.

Comment: Okey, still it's not possible to set it to dynamic. You need to set a "best fit value" which you think will work for most of your content.